# MySQL query with multiple conditions without WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I would like to query a database on several variables with different data types.

My query looks like:

```
SELECT var1, var2,  
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3 ='2008' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A1_U18_7',
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3='2015' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A34_U15_0',
       CASE WHEN var3 = '2015' AND var4 = 'A0_RISE' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END AS 'A0_RISE'
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY var1
```

Actually I don't need to sum up the result of the first two queries, but otherwise I would have got a "0" as an output. With the sum I got the right answer.

However, this workaround is unpracticable in the case of "A0_RISE" because the data type is text. Without the SUM function I got here the output "0", too.

How could I get the output right for all variables? If you have a better idea than the SUM-workaround for doubles, I would be very appreciated to here about that!

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: Not a nice solution, very ugly actually, but you could use MAX instead of SUM, in case there is always only 1 value you want to return

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the rule with GROUP BY (I'm really a newby), but I can't identify both as grouping column. Afterwards it will be used as a json and it should be grouped by var1, but I need var2 in the output.

Comment: The ugly solution with MAX works so far...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use Max ?

```
SELECT var1, var2,  
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3 ='2008' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A1_U18_7',
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3='2015' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A34_U15_0',
       MAX(CASE WHEN var3 = '2015' AND var4 = 'A0_RISE' THEN var5 ELSE '' END ) AS 'A0_RISE'
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY var1
```

Answer (score 0):

cast the **var5 to integer** like this `CAST(var5 AS UNSIGNED)` and add var2 in group by like `group by var1,var2`

```
SELECT var1, var2,  
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3 ='2008' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN CAST(var5 AS UNSIGNED) ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A1_U18_7',
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3='2015' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN CAST(var5 AS UNSIGNED) ELSE 0 END ) AS 'A34_U15_0',
       CASE WHEN var3 = '2015' AND var4 = 'A0_RISE' THEN CAST(var5 AS UNSIGNED) ELSE 0 END AS 'A0_RISE'
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY var1,var2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `group_concat()`?

```
SELECT var1, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN var3 ='2008' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS A1_U18_7,
       SUM( CASE WHEN var3='2015' AND var4='A1_U18' THEN var5 ELSE 0 END ) AS A34_U15_0,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN var3 = '2015' AND var4 = 'A0_RISE' THEN var5 END) AS A0_RISE
FROM dataset1
GROUP BY var1;
```

Do not include `var2` in the `SELECT`, unless you also include it in the `GROUP BY`.